# Screen flickering: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS | NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, amd-graphics

[image: Demo]

- Visible better at the edges. (See the top of the screen where the date and time is shown.)
- Not present always. Usually it start to show after a while and seems like there is a gradual increase.
- Will go away immediately after reboot.
- I have tried reinstalling the OS multiple times.

---

**Laptop:**

`ASUS TUF Gaming A17 Ryzen 5 Hexa Core 4600H`

**Graphics:**

`NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650/120 Hz`

**`uname -a` output:**

`Linux ubuntu 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 19 14:08:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**GNOME version:**

`3.36.8`

*Note: Unity is the default desktop environment in ubuntu. Changed it to GNOME.*

**Windows system:**

`X11`

**`nvidia-smi` output:**

```
Sat Feb 12 22:23:22 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C    P8     2W /  N/A |    268MiB /  4096MiB |      4%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1066      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 45MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1637      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 94MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1823      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               61MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4186      G   ...734834537552845246,131072       55MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**`prime-select` output:**

`Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query`

*Note: This laptop has an AMD GPU. Is showing intel in the output normal?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue seems to be fixed in the latest update.

I don't know the exact package. But it must be one of these.

```
Start-Date: 2022-02-15  23:38:52
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: anees (1000)

Upgrade:
google-chrome-stable:amd64 (98.0.4758.80-1, 98.0.4758.102-1),
python-apt-common:amd64 (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6, 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.7),
python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:20.04.36, 1:20.04.37),
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:20.04.36, 1:20.04.37),
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:20.04.36, 1:20.04.37),
libcryptsetup12:amd64 (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3, 2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.4),
linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187.25, 1.187.26),
python3-apt:amd64 (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6, 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.7)

End-Date: 2022-02-15  23:39:37
```

Comment: Thank you, upgrade helped. For me it's also upgraded all the cuda drivers.